# download a file using grails project

Tags: grails

i have a program with (".exe") type, i want to put a link in my grails project, when the user click it, this program download, how can i do this?

Comment: Is this .exe in your project's web-app or is it on another site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it in the you server download from there

example:

server name: server(dns name:www.server.com)

file name: file.exe

location on server: /downloads (in webapps in tomcat directory)

```
<a href="http://www.server.com/file.exe">download</a>
```

try this it may help you i find it true

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [static-resources plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/static-resources) for that.

Comment: it didn't work, do u know another way, or if their a trick in this plugin and i didn't know it, please mention it